# Datetime format for 12 or 24 hrs in C#

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, datetime-format

I have string datatype in one of the douments of mongodb collection in below formats.

```
// 24 hrs format//
string dt = "02/26/2020 23:43 PM"; 

// 12 hrs format//
 string dt = "02/22/2022 08:54 PM";
```

the data is dynamic and can be in 12 or 24 hrs format.
I am converting like this.

```
string dttime = Datetime.ParseExact(dt, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvarientCulture).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

but it is only working for 12 hours format.

Sly,it is working for 24 hours format.

```
string dttime = Datetime.ParseExact(dt, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvarientCulture).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

How can I handle it dynamically which will be valid for both the 12 and 24 hrs format?

Comment: `"02/26/2020 23:43 PM"` is invalid, `PM` is not supposed to be there.

Comment: There are "parse" overloads that accept multiple formats

Comment: @SergeyKalinichenko please see my edited post.Ineed to handle like this only.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing can u please suggest me the best possible way.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple with one of the `ParseExact` overloads:

```
DateTime
    .ParseExact("02/22/2022 23:54 AM", new[]
    {
        "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm tt",
        "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt"
    }, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

It just keeps trying patterns until one succeeds or they all fail.